# Regex for getting multiple words after a delimiter

Tags: python-3.x, regex, regex-recursion

I have been trying to get the separate groups from the below string using regex in PCRE:

`drop = blah blah blah something keep = bar foo nlah aaaa rename = (a=b d=e) obs=4 where = (foo > 45 and bar == 35)`

Groups I am trying to make is like:

```
1. drop = blah blah blah something
2. keep = bar foo nlah aaaa
3. rename = (a=b d=e)
4. obs=4
5. where = (foo > 45 and bar == 35)
```

I have written a regex using recursion but for some reason recursion is partially working for selecting multiple words after `drop` like it's selecting just first 3 words (blah blah blah) and not the 4th one. I have looked through various stackoverflow questions and have tried using positive lookahead also but this is the closest I could get to and now I am stuck because I am unable to understand what I am doing wrong.

The regex that I have written: `(?i)(drop|keep|where|rename|obs)\s*=\s*((\w+|\d+)(\s+\w+)(?4)|(\((.*?)\)))`

Same can be seen here: [RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/VeA5nf/1).

Any help on this or understanding what I am doing wrong is appreciated.

Comment: The subroutine looks redundant here, try `(?i)(drop|keep|where|rename|obs)\s*=\s*(?|(\w+(?:\s+\w+)*)(?=\s+\w+\s+=|$)|\((.*?)\))` ([demo](https://regex101.com/r/qAe88o/1)).

Comment: Just an idea but maybe you can split on a space where the right conditions are met? Like [so](https://regex101.com/r/Z94EY2/1)?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew This works..!! I wasn't aware of things like "Branch Reset Groups". Thanks for this. I am gonna look more about this and see if I can use these in future. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a [branch reset group](https://www.regular-expressions.info/branchreset.html) solution:

```
(?i)\b(drop|keep|where|rename|obs)\s*=\s*(?|(\w+(?:\s+\w+)*)(?=\s+\w+\s+=|$)|\((.*?)\))
```

See the [PCRE regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/qAe88o/3)

**Details**

- `(?i)` - case insensitive mode on
- `\b` - a word boundary
- `(drop|keep|where|rename|obs)` - Group 1: any of the words in the group
- `\s*=\s*` - a `=` char enclosed with 0+ whitespace chars
- `(?|` - start of a branch reset group:

  - `(\w+(?:\s+\w+)*)` - Group 2: one or more word chars followed with zero  or more repetitions of one or more whitespaces and one or more word chars
  - `(?=\s+\w+\s+=|$)` - up to one or more whitespaces, one or more word chars, one or more whitespaces, and `=`, or end of string
  - `|` - or

    - `\((.*?)\)` - `(`, then Group 2 capturing any zero or more chars other than line break chars, as few as possible and then `)`
- `)` - end of the branch reset group.

See [Python demo](https://tio.run/##XVDBasMwDL33K0TYQUpHLm0vAzcfMu/gEDUxS2zjeDQD/3smNxsbM1gWfk9Pjxc@0@jdadvsHHxMEHng9RBMShwdKIgVtpZ0h330Ib8zh3wfOXKO7MzM2XcL6aVWcrHNqO9HbF/0cpSGasJW7b1UlZ8oa8SmbkkTVYfEa5INVVGWt5vM@KcsfuY0WjdAWVpwE@HmPbiCGjmwWxAIjeqgV0wgdtQZHg7Lf@Ff4XwB4/qHgFJwusjuEK1LCK9rM0T/EZBEOsIK1u0JNDfreisZ4HcUz1Ds0hvQz@wvz0zTP5qwtu0L):

```
import regex
pattern = r"(?i)\b(drop|keep|where|rename|obs)\s*=\s*(?|(\w+(?:\s+\w+)*)(?=\s+\w+\s+=|$)|\((.*?)\))"
text = "drop = blah blah blah something keep = bar foo nlah aaaa rename = (a=b d=e) obs=4 where = (foo > 45 and bar == 35)"
print( [x.group() for x in regex.finditer(pattern, text)] )
# => ['drop = blah blah blah something', 'keep = bar foo nlah aaaa', 'rename = (a=b d=e)', 'obs=4', 'where = (foo > 45 and bar == 35)']
print( regex.findall(pattern, text) )
# => [('drop', 'blah blah blah something'), ('keep', 'bar foo nlah aaaa'), ('rename', 'a=b d=e'), ('obs', '4'), ('where', 'foo > 45 and bar == 35')]
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use the newer `regex` module with `DEFINE`:

```
(?(DEFINE)
    (?<key>\w+)
    (?<sep>\s*=\s*)
    (?<value>(?:(?!(?&key)(?&sep))[^()=])+)
    (?<par>\((?:[^()]+|(?&par))+\))
)
(?P<k>(?&key))(?&sep)(?P<v>(?:(?&value)|(?&par)))
```

See [**a demo on regex101.com**](https://regex101.com/r/hJT6jn/2/).

---

In `Python` this could be:

```
import regex as re

data = """
drop = blah blah blah something keep = bar foo nlah aaaa rename = (a=b d=e) obs=4 where = (foo > 45 and bar == 35)
"""

rx = re.compile(r'''
(?(DEFINE)
    (?<key>\w+)
    (?<sep>\s*=\s*)
    (?<value>(?:(?!(?&key)(?&sep))[^()=])+)
    (?<par>\((?:[^()]+|(?&par))+\))
)

(?P<k>(?&key))(?&sep)(?P<v>(?:(?&value)|(?&par)))''', re.X)

result = {m.group('k').strip(): m.group('v').strip()
          for m in rx.finditer(data)}

print(result)
```

And yields

```
{'drop': 'blah blah blah something', 'keep': 'bar foo nlah aaaa', 'rename': '(a=b d=e)', 'obs': '4', 'where': '(foo > 45 and bar == 35)'}
```

Comment: Thanks..!! this works too. I have been avoiding to build a parser for this because it's not really a bigger functionality that needs to be used at too many places so decided to go with regex instead. for multiple parentheses. I will check but it's a good starting point for me. Can you also please explain the <value> named regex once. That would help it understand more. Thanks again..!! :)